# Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I'm aware questions have been asked which are the same as mine but I did in fact try suggestions and got nothing, so i'd see if anyone could work it out from my code here.

I have a LoginViewController which is known as WelcomeVC in that i have a button which signs the user into the app, once they've signed in if everything goes ok it loads the TabBarVC which has 5 UIViewControllers connected to it through relationship 'viewcontrollers' however this was working fine literally 20 minutes ago but for some reason when i went to test this on the simulator to show a client it seemed to crash when trying to sign in.

The code I have is as followed:

```
@IBAction func signUserIn(sender: AnyObject) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(usernameTF.text!, password: passwordTF.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("email/pass is wrong!")
        }
        else
        {
                let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
                let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tBVC") as! TabBarVC
                self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
        }

    })
}
```

This worked fine before and loads the next view programatically, not through any segue's. Any suggestions to why it's suddenly stopped working and any idea on how to fix it?

this is the error code:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x1119548b0) to 'LT_Apps.TabBarVC' (0x10e4e9980).
(lldb)
```

Comment: Did you try again to get exception message in console?

Comment: please see the edit to my post, i added the error from Xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't set the class of `UITabBarController`. Like this:
[image]

**Updated:**
1. Did `TabBarVC` class exist?
2. Did `TabBarVC` inherit `UITabBarController`?
If both is yes,just copy paste `TabBarVC` to its class item. And build it!

Comment: It doesn't let me set the Class, any idea why?

Comment: Click the 3rd button from left. In inspectors view.

Comment: @Konsy Because your `TabBarVC` didn't inherit `UITabBarController `.

Comment: @Lumialxk my TabBarVC is set as a UITabBarController and it still won't let me set it??

Comment: @Konsy Try to clean and rebuild. And then set it again.

Comment: @Konsy Updated my answer.

Comment: @Konsy check another two things. Did it in `Main Storyboard`? Was its storyboard identifier "tBVC"?

Comment: @Lumialxk i fixed it! Thanks for the help :) I just deleted TabBarVC.swift and added it in again and it seemed to work fine o.O